# Creating QIcon from SVG contents in memory

Tags: c++, qt, plugins

How can we create the `QIcon` object having SVG icon contents in the memory buffer?

P.S. Initially wanted to create QSvgIconEngine, but it is hidden on the plugins layer, and I can not create it explicitly. How can I do it with loading from plugin (taking in account, that plugin is loaded)?

Comment: You can use SVG without explicitly using QSvgIconEngine. You need just to use SVG?

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately I need to create QIcon from memory without filename.

Answer (score 15):

After digging for a while here and there, and digging in how QIcon itself uses an svg file to load an icon, here's what I learned:

- `QIcon`, when called with an svg file (or any other image type for that matter), it calles `addFile()` subsequently, which only uses the extension of the file (called `QFileInfo::suffix` in Qt) to determine the method that converts the image file to an icon.
- The method (semantically speaking) is determined by a `QIconEngine` instance
- `QIconEngine` classes for every image type are not apparently simply accessible by us (the Qt developers); apparently there's a plugin system to be used and it's not available at compile-time (not simply at least)

On the other hand; How does QIcon work? When an icon is requested from QIcon, it uses the information passed to it to determine what engine to use, and creates an instance of the engine. Then, every time the icon needs to draw something, it asks the engine to draw an icon with some size given to it. The size is used on the function `QIconEngine::pixmap()`, which creates a pixmap with the required size, then the method `QIconEngine::paint()` is used to paint on that pixmap.

So, given this information, the solution is simply to write an Icon Engine that QIcon will use in order to generate the icon depending on the size passed to it. Here's how to do that:

So here's the header file SvgIconEngine.h

```
#ifndef SVGICONENGINE_H
#define SVGICONENGINE_H

#include <QIconEngine>
#include <QSvgRenderer>

class SVGIconEngine : public QIconEngine {

  QByteArray data;

public:
  explicit SVGIconEngine(const std::string &iconBuffer);
  void paint(QPainter *painter, const QRect &rect, QIcon::Mode mode,
             QIcon::State state) override;
  QIconEngine *clone() const override;
  QPixmap pixmap(const QSize &size, QIcon::Mode mode,
                 QIcon::State state) override;
signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // SVGICONENGINE_H
```

And here's the implementation, SvgIconEngine.cpp

```
#include "SvgIconEngine.h"
#include <QPainter>

SVGIconEngine::SVGIconEngine(const std::string &iconBuffer) {
  data = QByteArray::fromStdString(iconBuffer);
}

void SVGIconEngine::paint(QPainter *painter, const QRect &rect,
                          QIcon::Mode mode, QIcon::State state) {
  QSvgRenderer renderer(data);
  renderer.render(painter, rect);
}

QIconEngine *SVGIconEngine::clone() const { return new SVGIconEngine(*this); }

QPixmap SVGIconEngine::pixmap(const QSize &size, QIcon::Mode mode,
                              QIcon::State state) {
  // This function is necessary to create an EMPTY pixmap. It's called always
  // before paint()

  QImage img(size, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
  img.fill(qRgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  QPixmap pix = QPixmap::fromImage(img, Qt::NoFormatConversion);
  {
    QPainter painter(&pix);
    QRect r(QPoint(0.0, 0.0), size);
    this->paint(&painter, r, mode, state);
  }
  return pix;
}
```

Notice: You must override `clone()`, because it's an abstract method, and you must override `pixmap()`, because without that, you'll not have an empty pixmap to paint the svg on.

To use this, simply do this:

```
std::string iconSvgData = GetTheSvgPlainData();
QIcon theIcon(new SVGIconEngine(iconSvgData));
//Use the icon!
```

Notice that QIcon takes ownership of the engine object. It'll destroy it when it's destroyed.

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code. But I'm curious how to solve QIcon::Move and QIcon::State handling. If I didn't miss anything, it's necessary to handle it in two steps, in first step use SvgRenderer->render and than use QIcon.paint(...mode,state). But this is very inneficient ;-(

Comment: Sorry. I did this over 3 years ago. I can't remember details.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have c++ at hand, but it should be easy to convert:

```
QtGui.QIcon(
  QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(
    QtGui.QImage.fromData(
       b'<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 32 32"'
       b' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">'
       b'<circle cx="16" cy="16" r="4.54237"/></svg>')))
```

This code will create transparent 32 by 32 pixels icon with a black circle.

Comment: That does not render a scalable Icon. The SVG is converted to a bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

> How can we create the `QIcon` object having `SVG` icon contents in the
>   memory buffer?

For that all the required functionality is delivered via external interface of [QSvgRenderer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsvgrenderer.html) class. To construct that type of renderer we need to use either of:

```
QSvgRenderer(const QByteArray &contents, QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
QSvgRenderer(QXmlStreamReader *contents, QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
```

or we can just load the content with:

```
bool QSvgRenderer::load(const QByteArray &contents)
bool QSvgRenderer::load(QXmlStreamReader *contents)
```

And to create the actual icon:

```
QIcon svg2Icon(const QByteArray& svgContent, QPainter::CompositionMode mode = 
   QPainter::CompositionMode_SourceOver)
{
    return QIcon(util::svg2Pixmap(svgContent, QSize(128, 128), mode));
}

QPixmap svg2Pixmap(const QByteArray& svgContent,
   const QSize& size,
   QPainter::CompositionMode mode)
{
    QSvgRenderer rr(svgContent);
    QImage image(size.width(), size.height(), QImage::Format_ARGB32);
    QPainter painter(&image);
    painter.setCompositionMode(mode);
    image.fill(Qt::transparent);
    rr.render(&painter);
    return QPixmap::fromImage(image);
}
```

We can also use other composition modes as well, say, 
`QPainter::RasterOp_NotSourceOrDestination` to invert the icon color.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the solution. The point is not to get QIcon, but and QIcon, containing SVG. For example, after switching to different QScreen with different pixel ratio to make possible the QIcon to be rerendered basing on vector SVG. So, I guess, it is possible only with underlying QSvgIconEngine.

Comment: That is not how to ensure the pixel accuracy. Either you call `QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
 QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps)`; before the `QApplication` object created in `main.cpp` OR handle the corresponding event with updating all the controls in the widget. Even if you get to that `QSvgIconEngine` it will not resolve that problem. That same thing required. `QIcon` won't redraw anything by itself. It is an icon data container.

Comment: It's quite weird and strangely stupid that Qt doesn't have the option to load an icon from a memory buffer. I haven't tried @AlexanderVX solution yet, but it would be MUCH easier, reliable and portable to stupidly just write that to a file and then use a `QIcon`'s constructor, and then erase the file.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist There is a way to load an icon from memory buffer. First you construct QPixmap: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#QIcon-1 One way to do so...

Comment: Today I learned the right way without a pixmap. I'll be posting it here later.

Comment: @AlexanderVX Check my new answer if you wish. Have a nice day :)

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist The problem with that is SVGIconEngine not being public class or not intended to be used directly. No way `#include "SvgIconEngine.h"` is a good way. Should there be public class: #include <QSvgIconEngine.h>`. At least that I know of Qt for sure.

Comment: @Alex Dude! That's my class, not a class from Qt. Please read the code carefully. I'm inheriting from `QIconEngine`.